# Matlab - ODE45 - change the number of time steps

Tags: matlab, ode45

I have a function with the handle `@func` with initial condition `y0` that I want to test over `t = [0, tspan]`. What, exactly, do I need to do to increase the *number* of time steps `ode45` uses, without changing `tspan`?

I saw the MATLAB documentation of `ode45` and saw that I need to somehow change the `options` input to `ode45`. However, I do not really understand how to do this because no example code was provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) which creates an options structure to be used in ODE solvers, like `ode45`.  You're looking at changing the `MaxStep` parameter.

The documentation for this (MATLAB R2015a) says:

> `MaxStep` - Upper bound on step size  [ positive scalar ]
>
> `MaxStep` defaults to one-tenth of the `tspan` interval in all solvers.

Therefore, you can make it something smaller than `0.1*tspan`... something like `1e-6` or something like that.  This depends on what `tspan` is, so you'll need to make it smaller than `0.1*tspan` if you want to increase the total number of time steps / output points.

As such, create an `odeset` structure and override the `MaxStep` parameter.  The rest of the values will remain as default:

```
options = odeset('MaxStep', 1e-6);
```

Now that you're done, call `ode45` on your problem:

```
[tout,yout] = ode45(@func, tspan, y0, options);
```

---

Simply play around with the `MaxStep` until you get the desired granularity.

## Minor Note

Though a bit buried, the documentation *does* tell you on how to change the options.  This is the section that talks about how to call `ode45` with options.  Please take note of what is highlighted in bold.  This is the documentation for MATLAB R2015a:

> `[TOUT,YOUT] = ode45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0,OPTIONS)` solves as above with default
>   integration properties replaced by values in `OPTIONS`, **an argument created
>   with the `ODESET` function. See `ODESET` for details**. Commonly used options 
>   are scalar relative error tolerance `'RelTol'` (`1e-3` by default) and vector
>   of absolute error tolerances `'AbsTol'` (all components `1e-6` by default).
>   If certain components of the solution must be non-negative, use
>   `ODESET` to set the `'NonNegative'` property to the indices of these
>   components.